# Not receiving onActivityResult when finish authenticate with Neura

Tags: android, onactivityresult, neura

I'm using [Neura sdk](https://dev.theneura.com/docs/guide/android/sdk) in order to detect when i arrive and leave home.

My application sends feedback to the user's selected contacts when he arrives and leaves home. 
I've initiated connection with neura api, as declared in their documentations, and called [authenticate](https://dev.theneura.com/docs/guide/android/sdk#authenticate). However, when authenticating with neura(basically, did a login), I'm not receiving the response onActivityResult.

Here's my code : 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int NEURA_AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private NeuraApiClient mNeuraApiClient;
private ArrayList<Permission> mPermissions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Builder builder = new Builder(this);
    mNeuraApiClient = builder.build();
    mNeuraApiClient.setAppUid(getResources().getString(R.string.app_uid));
    mNeuraApiClient.setAppSecret(getResources().getString(R.string.app_secret));
    mNeuraApiClient.connect();

    mPermissions = Permission.list(new String[]
            {"userLeftWork", "userArrivedHome", "userStartedWalking"});

    AuthenticationRequest request = new AuthenticationRequest();
    request.setPermissions(mPermissions);

    mNeuraApiClient.authenticate(NEURA_AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST_CODE, request);
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == NEURA_AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == FragmentActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine to me, as long as

1. app_uid is set to your own project.
2. app_secret is set to your own project.

I think that if app_uid and app_secret are right, than you need to check if the package you've declared in [your application](https://dev.theneura.com/console) :

[image: package_name_neura_dev_site]

matches your main package in the code (in gradle & manifest)

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! this was my problem - i didn't set the right package name in the 'Application Package Name'